# Manipulating Multi dimension array

Tags: php

I have a  Multi dimension array and what i 'd like to do is put array to insert the element in each column

for example

Multi dimension array :

```
Tony 14
Peter 20
```

I would like to insert them into a different array , so that

```
column0[]={Tony, Peter}
column1[]={14, 20}
```

Since i do not know the actual no of column , how can i achieve this?

```
   for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; $row++) {
        for ($y = 0; $y < $highestColumn; $y++) {
    ................what should be added here................
            }
        }
```

Thank you

Comment: I don't see *multidimensional* array in your question

Comment: @zerkms I think he means that the rows are one dimension, the columns are the second :)

Comment: @Jack: ok. But anyway I'd better go with array in `php` syntax, that doesn't allow different meanings in terms ;-)

Comment: @user782104 Where are you getting the data from? Excel sheet, CSV file, etc.? Maybe you could post a small subset of the data?

Comment: from spreadsheet, but is that affect ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the code below. All you're doing in your actual loop, is swapping the $y and the $row

```
<?php
$original_array = array(
    array('Tony', 14),
    array('Peter', 20)
);

print_r($original_array);

// Array
// (
//     [0] => Array
//         (
//             [0] => Tony
//             [1] => 14
//         )

//     [1] => Array
//         (
//             [0] => Peter
//             [1] => 20
//         )

// )

$new_array = array();

for ($row = 0; $row < count($original_array); $row++) {
    for ($y = 0; $y < count($original_array[0]); $y++) {
        $new_array[$y][$row] = $original_array[$row][$y];
    }
}

print_r($new_array);

// Array
// (
//     [0] => Array
//         (
//             [0] => Tony
//             [1] => Peter
//         )

//     [1] => Array
//         (
//             [0] => 14
//             [1] => 20
//         )

// )
```